# sein or werden?

Tags: passive, past-participle

I would like to show examples first of all. I have been confused over months.

- sein

Present: Ich bin verabredet.
Past: Ich war verabredet.

- werden

Present: Ich werde überholt.
Past: Ich wurde überholt. => to avoid confusion, I would like to change the example to - My Auto wurde überholt.

The question is, why in the second example I cannot say: ich bin oder war überholt? How could I better understand the sein and werden here.

Comment: Related [How to recognise *when* to use a passive construction?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/how-to-recognise-when-to-use-a-passive-construction). The accepted answer there explains the question.

Answer (score 6):

In your context ***"werden"*** is a **passive operation** (Vorgangspassiv), where something is happing and ***"sein"*** is a **passive state** (Zustandspassiv), where something just is.

"Verabredet sein" is a state, you **are** *'verabredet'*

"Überholt werden" is an operation, you are **being** *'überholt'*

Comment: Side note: Since I don't know the translations of 'Vorgangs-' and Zustandspassiv' I just used google translate, so they may be not correctly translated

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the one between *überholen* and *überholt sein*, which are totally different!

*Überholen* means *to overtake/pass*, like *The car overtook/passed us at great speed.*
*Überholt sein* means *to be outdated*, like *This version is outdated (get the most recent one)*.

You can only build a passive form of *überholen*, *überholt sein* is some kind of idiom which takes *überholt* as an attribute/adverb and not as a participle. So *überholt* is context sensitive, in connection with *sein* it is an attribute/adverb and in connection with *werden* it is a participle.

*Ich bin überholt* would mean *I am outdated*, which would most likely not be said by anyone ;-)
*Ich bin überholt worden* means *Someone has overtaken/passed me (because he is faster in the race still happening)*.

Comment: I disagree. The different meanings of 'überholen' are not distinctive based on grammatical context. 'Ich wurde überholt' can just as well mean 'I was overtaken', 'I was superseded' or 'I was overhauled'.

Comment: OK, mentioning the context may be misunderstood. I meant the context related to the content of a sentence rather than a grammatical context. And of course, "Ich wurde überholt" can just mean what you wrote, but will still be different to "Ich bin überholt" (without "worden").

Comment: 'Ich bin überholt' can just as well mean 'I am overtaken', 'I am superseded' or 'I am overhauled'. The *meaning* of 'überholen' is simply not related to the choice of grammatical voice or tense.

Comment: There is definitely a difference in meaning between just *jemanden überholen*, *etwas überholen* and *überholt sein*, so the context is relevant...

Comment: @jarnbjo Please tell me any situation when anybody (a person) would say *I am overhauled*. Would an English native speaker ever say that? A German native speaker would not even say *Ich bin überholt* as a joke. Maybe a personified machine or software system would do so in a comic or cgi movie and then mean *I need an update*.

Comment: From a grammatical or language viewpoint, the statement is valid. Not everything you can express with a language actually makes logical sense. Google will find you a few thousand examples on how 'I am overhauled' is actually used, be it funny, sarcastic or figuratively.

Comment: OK, lets say it's pretty difficult! I am German and have never heard *Ich bin überholt* but *Ich bin überholt worden* is very common. though its meaning is totally depending on the context. It is the present perfect form of *I have been overhauled (by a maintenance worker)* as well as the present perfect form of *I have been overtaken (by something/-one faster)*. In some future, an artificial intelligence is probably going to say something like the first example.